# How to get all values through join?

Tags: google-bigquery

Here is my query:

```
WITH
  basis AS (
  SELECT
    account
  FROM
    `project.temp.basis`) (
  SELECT
    feature,
    COUNT(DISTINCT
    IF
      (in_audience IS TRUE, account, NULL)) AS in_audience,
    COUNT(DISTINCT
    IF
      (in_audience IS FALSE, account, NULL)) AS not_in_audience
  FROM (
    SELECT
      DISTINCT account,
      CASE
        WHEN account = feature_account THEN TRUE
      ELSE
      FALSE
    END
      AS in_audience,
      feature
    FROM (
      SELECT
        account
      FROM
        basis)
    LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT
        _TABLE_SUFFIX AS feature,
        account AS feature_account
      FROM
        `project.temp.*`
    ON
      account = feature_account)
  GROUP BY
    feature)
```

I understand that feature is NULL after the JOIN when account value only appears on the left side of the join, however, it's not what I am trying to look at.
At the end I want to have a list of features with one count of all accounts that are in the feature table and another count of all accounts not in the feature table. I'm not sure if this can be done with my query, maybe I'm going about this the wrong way entirely.

Comment: Can you provide 1. Table schemas, 2. Goal specification, 3. Sample input, 4. Expected output, 5. How your attempt failed. Currently your problem statement is not very clear and I find it hard to infer what exactly you want.